# iOS: sharing a transparent UIImage w/ UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, uiimage, png, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

So I am using UIActivityViewController to let users share or save an image they create with my app.  I include a UIImage as one of the share items, it all works fine.

Except: it is possible to create this image with some transparent areas.  And it looks to me like the built-in UIActivities all create JPEG representations of the UIImage, thus losing the transparency.

Is there a way to force it to use a PNG representation so as not to lose the alpha channel?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Without seeing some code it may be difficult to fully answer the question. Have you tried converting your UIImage to an NSData object using `UIImagePNGRepresentation` and sharing the NSdata object instead of the image itself? I would have put this in a comment rather than an answer, but I lack the rep.

Reference for `UIImagePNGRepresentation`:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation

Comment: That did it! So glad to know it was as simple as that -- just didn't even occur to me to share an NSData object.