# Swift 4 Data to UIImage as PNG

Tags: ios, swift

I have these two lines of code that take Data and turns it into an UIImage, however the UIImage is a jpeg when I goto share it, how do I get it as a png and possibly set the file name?

```
let key = Data(base64Encoded: self.array[indexPath.row]["image"] as! String)!

let image = UIImage(data: key)
```

And this is how I am sharing it:

```
@IBAction func shareButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        var imageToShare: Array<UIImage> = []

        for item in (collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems)!
        {

            let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: item) as! ImageCollectionCell

            imageToShare.append(cell.imageView.image!)

        }

        //Create Share Popup

        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

        //Assign source view

        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

        //Present share popup

        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: How are you sharing the image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: sharing a transparent UIImage w/ UIActivityViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689926/ios-sharing-a-transparent-uiimage-w-uiactivityviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIImage` supports a variety of data types. The `UIActivityViewController` determines whether to share the image data as a PNG or JPEG (or other types), probably based on the underlying data in the image and/or the application/activity selected to share the data.

If you need it to be a PNG you can use `pngData()` on the image and share the `Data` object from that instead, but you can't necessarily guarantee that the app the user selects to share the image doesn't convert it to whatever it wants to use.

Answer (score 0):

First, think of a `UIImage` instance as a decoded generic bitmap image without any particular format to it. The `UIImage` can be *loaded from* all sorts of data formats, including JPEG or PNG or etc, but once it's loaded up, it doesn't have a format or type to it.

Your image data appears to be provided to you in the form of a base64-encoded string. That string, which becomes binary data within the `key` `Data` object, does have some inherent image format to it. Yours may be a PNG or it may be a JPG-- I can't tell from the info in the question, and it doesn't necessarily matter. The idea is that `UIImage` does you a convenience by loading your `key` image data in any format. And it is also able to produce an encoded object of image data in the format you request later, if you wish. The share activity doesn't let you do that though-- it will choose the format for you, based on some internal rules (maybe resulting size, quality, features like transparency, etc). Sounds like for you, it's picking a JPG.

If you want to share the image, but you *always want to only provide it as a PNG*, then you'll probably have ask for the encoding yourself and share it as a file (with a type and filename).

I.e. if you need to encode the image to a PNG, you will indeed need to instantiate the `UIImage`, and then ask it for `.pngData()`, and use that `Data`. **However,** if you know for sure that your original data (`key`) was already in PNG format and you just want to use that, then you don't need to use the `UIImage` to round-trip the data, you can just use your original `key` as your PNG file.

If you go the route of providing your file directly, then you can either save that data to disk (`/tmp` seems right) and provide the URL to the activity view controller as the `activityItems`, or you can probably do it directly with the in-memory `Data`, but this may require you to create a small container class around the data object that implements the [`UIActivityItemSource` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityitemsource) in order to be able to provide information about e.g. the type to the share sheet.

A good question for you of course is: why do you only want a PNG file here? Is there a reason why just using the default share activity behavior doesn't work for you?